# Is the phrasal verb "sober up" interchangeable with "sober down"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I understand that phrasal verbs are extremely idiosyncratic.

If I have to replace -Sober up or calm down, would **sober down** be an appropriate choice, and a formal alternative.

Edit: Or **can i conclude** that the underlying logic only involves metaphorical meanings of the adverbial particle (i.e., up/down etc.) 
and therefore, phrasal verbs referring to increment tend to use 'up' 
(fire someone up, be hyped up, rev up, etc), while 'decrease' is one of the meanings of phrasal verbs with 'down' (calm down, settle down, die down, etc).

Comment: No it is either 'sober-up' or 'calm-down'.

Comment: There's an `UP/DOWN` metaphor working here. Sober people are erect, while calm people are seated. So the completive sense of _up_ works with _sober_, and the _down to the ground_ sense of _down_ works with _calm_, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answers are given by dictionaries. The two expression don't mean the same.
Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English says:

to sober down - meaning to become more serious in behaviour or attitude.

to sober up - meaning gradually to become less drunk.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sober_2